# How to save the Custom cell Content

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have tried [this](http://kshitizghimire.com.np/insert-customuitableviewcell-in-uitablevew-on-row-selected/) url to insert uitextfield in custom cell but what i am not sure is when to save the modified content.

Please let me know and thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "when to save the modified content"? The linked tutorial does not add an additional UITextField. It just shows how to change the value of the standard fields. If you want to add one then you could add it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. It may be smart to subclass UITableViewCell, create and add the new TextField appropriately, layout it in the layoutSubviews method and set its value in the Table View Controller's cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to make the your UITableViewController implement the UITextFieldDelegate protocol, then assign it as the delegate of the UITextField embedded in your CustomCell UITableViewCellSubclass.

You'll firstly need to implement the UITextFieldDelegate protocol in your table view controller subclass...

```
MyTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Then in your subclass add an implementation for the textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField method.  This method will be called when the user finished editing the content's of your cell's UITextField...

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSString *enteredText = [textField text];
    // .. do something with the text
}
```

Lastly you'll need to set your CustomCell's UITextField's delegate property to be your UITableViewController subclass.  To do this simply add a single method call to your existing tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method...

```
cell.textField.delegate = self;
```

Comment: :thanks for the reply, can you pls tell me how to identify which cell get modified?